# Plank - How i can add on dock a folder like home/fred/mymusic?

Tags: plank

I try to move on plank but the system just starts the file manager.

I would like to have an icon to start the file manager and another one to start the file manager on a path I choose.

Ty guys

Comment: Nope, i like your link but i want a single link to a path on my system like i said (ex. /home/fred/gimp/test)

Comment: This is already answered on that page. I proposed an edit to clarify. In your case you only need to do step 3: Drag the folder to Plank.

Comment: Daniel you are right, my fault. 
Many thanks